# Check for last saved item that ignores Object.new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a standard Rails view that displays a warning box on a date condition on the `new.html.erb` page.

```
<% if @user.items.last.issue_date + 2.years > Date.today %>
  ...show warning...
<% end %>
```

This will choke though because the last record associate with the user the empty object created in the controller for the form

```
def new
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @item = @user.items.new
end
```

It appears that I can get around this by doing

```
<% if @user.items.offset(0).last.issue_date + 2.years > Date.today %>
```

but this seems like it shouldn't work at all because the Postgres docs say

[OFFSET 0 is the same as omitting the OFFSET clause.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/queries-limit.html)

So, I have 2 questions:

- Is there a better way to check against only records that have been saved in the database?
- Why is the ActiveRecord offset call behavior (apparently) different from what the Postgres docs say it should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new `@item` you brought into existence in the controller is in your `@user.items` collection, but is not yet saved to the database.

That is why adding `.offset(0)` is working for you, because like a `.where()` clause, you are altering the *conditions* of the records returned, to only ones returned from the database, of which your new record is not one of.

An alternative way to filter that out may be like this:

```
@user.items.reject(&:new_record?).last
```

Or this:

```
@user.items.reject { |item| item == @item }.last
```

However, `.reject` will be less performant than pulling from the database for a large number or records.

Otherwise, what you have works, but I would use a less brittle (offsets could change) and more intention-revealing query like this:

```
@user.items.
  where('issue_date < ?', 2.years.ago).
  order(issue_date: :desc).
  limit(1).
  last
```

And ideally, you can wrap this up in a `User` query method or scope in the model named something like `@user.issues.expired` or `@user.issued_less_than(2.years.ago)`, or whatever works for your app.

Also, I hope that `@user.items` is ordered on the relationship, because Postgres doesn't always return items in any specific order unless you specify one.

```
has_many :items, -> { order(id: :desc) }
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the answer and the added insight!